# ReactiveMongo & Play: How to compare two DateTime instances

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I use [Play-ReactiveMongo](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo) to interact with MongoDB... and I'm wondering how to compare two dates considering that I don't use BSON in my application. Let me provide you with an example:

```
def isTokenExpired(tokenId: String): Future[Boolean] = {

  var query = collection.genericQueryBuilder.query(
    Json.obj(
      "_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> tokenId),
      "expirationTime" -> Json.obj("$lte" -> DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC))
    )
  ).options(QueryOpts(skipN = 0))

  query.cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](1).map {
    case Some(_) => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

`isTokenExpired` does not work as expected since `expirationTime` is considered a `String` – I've an implicit `Writes` that serializes a `DateTime` as `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`... and this is correct since I want a human-readable JSON.

That said, how do I get a document from a collection that has a `DateTime` less than another `DateTime`? The following doesn't seem to work:

```
Json.obj(
  "_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> tokenId),
  "expirationTime" -> Json.obj("$lte" -> Json.obj("$date" -> DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis))
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've an implicit Writes that serializes a DateTime as "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"... and this is correct since I want a human-readable JSON.

If you store your DateTime as a string in MongoDB then `$lte` won't compare the dates.

You should store your `DateTime` as as date in MongoDB (with `$date`) so you can use your second query (the one with `$lte` and `$date`).

> I want a human-readable JSON

Why do you need human-readable JSON? I don't see any reason against the date datatype (If you need human-readable JSON in your API then convert your date field there).
The MongoDB dates are readable. Output in MongoDB shell:

```
PRIMARY> db.mycollection.findOne()
{
     "creation" : ISODate("2014-01-16T14:45:27.441Z")
}
```

Comment: When I say "human-readable JSON" I mean the JSON returned by my Scala API, not the JSON rendered by the mongo console - maybe I wasn't clear enough ;-)